# Which shall I convert a byte stream first, buffer stream or char stream?

Tags: java, io

To get a buffered char stream for a given byte stream, which shall I convert the byte stream to first, a buffer stream or a char stream?

1. Given an `OutputStream` object `os` (such as `FileOutputStream`
   object or `System.out`), there seems to be two ways to get a
   buffered char stream:

   ```
   new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

   new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
   ```

   What differences are between them?
2. Given an `InputStream` object `is` (such as `FileInputStream` object
   or `System.in`), there seems to be two ways to get a buffered char
   stream:

   ```
   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is));
   ```

   What differences are between them?

Answer (score 0):

1. As stated in javadoc for [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

> The characters passed to the write() methods are not buffered.
>   **For top efficiency, consider wrapping an OutputStreamWriter within a BufferedWriter so as to avoid frequent converter invocations.**  For example:
>   Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

Since resulting bytes after conversion are accumulated in a buffer, there is no need to in-pipe BufferedStream after OutputStreamWriter

Thus, the conventional way is to use:

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
```

2. Similar reason for [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)

Use:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you recommend `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os))` over `new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os))`? Doesn't `new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os))` also have buffer from `BufferedOutputStream` for similar efficiency purpose to  `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os))`?

Comment: Do you recommend new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os)) over new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os))? - Yes.
Doesn't new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os)) also have buffer from BufferedOutputStream - it will have buffer for BufferedOutputStream, but you need to buffer OutputStreamWriter to avoid frequent converter invocation

Comment: why? Doesn't new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(os)) also have buffer from BufferedOutputStream for similar efficiency purpose to new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os))?